Linq Contains without a variable name
I have this block of code which works
str1 = ["Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4", "Element 5"];
var mystring = "Element 1";
bool found = str1.Contains(mystring);

I'd like to do this without having to use the variable str1 because I am working inside of a third-party tool for writing expressions that doesn't allow creating variables and I need to hard code a list of elements. Note:mystring will be replaced by an input from the tool itself.
So something like this, but that actually works
["Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4", "Element 5"].Contains(mystring);
Can this be done?

why is var mystring = "Element 1"; allowed when you can't declare variables?

old school array declaration isn't good enough? https://dotnetfiddle.net/s8iQ5p

@RandRandom I clarified this on edit... it will be replaced by a variable that the tool understands already... an input from the calling application.

@RandRandom I think you have the solution. Thank you.

Collection expressions do not have a natural type yet (this feature will probably be added in a future version of C#). I.e., you can only use them when the target type is known. Therefore, as @RandRandom pointed out, use an array initializer instead: new[] { "a", "b", "c" }.

Even if you could use Collection expressions, you would only save a few bytes in code.

If you seek brevity, why bother with a collection at all? "Element 1\nElement 2\nElement 3\nElement 4\nElement 5".Contains("Element 1")

The most compact syntax to do that right now would be:
(new [] {"Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4", "Element 5"}).Contains(mystring);

Whether your third-party tool would allow it is another question. Unfortunately there's not yet a syntax in C# for collection "constants" like Python and other languages.

C# 12 introduced Collection expressions (collection "constants" if you will). The problem here is that the target type must be known.

If we're golfing, "12345".Any(x=>$"Element {x}"=="Element 1") ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
